# div nested inside a gives weird innerHTML result in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, innerhtml

In IE 8, jQuery acts as I would expect:

```
$('div',$('<a><div></div></a>')).html('test').html()
"test"
```

In FireFox:

```
$('div',$('<a><div></div></a>')).html('test').html()
"<a>test</a>"
```

It puts anchors around what I wanted. Does anyone know why this would happen?

**EDIT:** Setting this with plain javascript (i.e. setting innerHTML) causes the problem. So I guess my real question is: why does firefox change what I set? Is this part of some esoteric specification, or is it a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrapping an `<a>` around a `<div>` is invalid html. Maybe Firefox is fixing it for you on the fly and returning the valid html?

Comment: Maybe, but it accepts divs inside a's in static html just fine. I guess it's not impossible that it has extra fixing stuff for dynamic html, but it seems weird.

Comment: I don't mean to say that firefox will edit your html. More that it might interpret the HTML in the DOM differently than the static html suggests.

Comment: Even though it might work fine in some browsers (IE, surprisingly) - I recommend you try to make it valid HTML.  It'll make your life easier when it comes to debugging and validation enforcement.

Comment: I asked on jQuery and they said basically this - block inside inline isn't expected to work, so the result of setting innerHTML like this is undefined. So marking this as the answer, although Reigel posted a good workaround.

Answer (score 3):

well, firefox maybe knows you're breaking the rules.

but it did not know you did if you use `.append()`.

```
$('div',$('<a><div></div></a>')).html('').append('test').html(); // give you 'test'
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it applies here (as we dont know which doctype you're using) but wrapping an `<a>` around a `<div>` is perfectly valid in html5, but Firefox obviously isn't up to speed on that yet. I'm guessing FF4 will be though

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with Firefox 3.6.18 (4.x, 5.x renders page correctly). Quick and dirty fix which I came up was to wrap everything inside <a> with <span>.